# Play! 2.1 sbt publish a dist cycle in tasks error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, artifactory

Upon migrating from 2.04 to 2.1, we encountered a problem with our publish task that sends the zip file from the dist task to Artifactory.

Now what we are getting is the folowing error:

```
Internal task engine error: nothing running.  This usually indicates a cycle in tasks.
```

There is discussion about this in the play framework user groups:

> https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/535

and

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/BoWw65F6vg8

We basically tried to do what they recommend but we are getting nowhere. Could someone please give us an example of what the Build.scala should look like?

What we have is the following:

```
  /*
    In order to solve the cycle generated during the dist task in play 2.1
  */
  val distHack = TaskKey[File]("dist-hack", "Hack to publish dist")

  val myDistSettings = Seq[Setting[_]] (
      publish <<= (publish) dependsOn play.Project.dist,
      publishLocal <<= (publishLocal) dependsOn play.Project.dist,
      artifact in distHack ~= { (art: Artifact) =>
        art.copy(`type` = "zip", extension = "zip")
      },
      distHack <<= (distDirectory, version) map { (d, v) =>
        val packageName = "%s-%s" format(appName, v)
        println(packageName)
        val zip = d / (packageName + ".zip")
        zip
      }
    ) ++ Seq(addArtifact(artifact in distHack, distHack).settings: _*)

    lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
        ...
    .settings(addArtifact(Artifact(appName, "zip","zip"), dist).settings : _*)
            ...
    .settings(
        // disable publishing the main jar produced by `package`
        publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false,

        // disable publishing the main API jar
        publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := true,

        // disable publishing the main sources jar
        publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false,
        publishArtifact in Test := false,
        crossPaths := false, 
        publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "somewhere"),
        credentials += Credentials(".credentials"),
        scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")
    )
    .settings(myDistSettings: _*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the dist task and publish task where in a cycle. So all we had to do is have the publish task depend on **distHack**. In other words, we replaced this:

```
.settings(addArtifact(Artifact(appName, "zip","zip"), dist).settings : _*)
```

with

```
.settings(addArtifact(Artifact(appName, "zip","zip"), distHack).settings : _*)
```

There was also another problem. The main app.jar was not being included in the dist. So we had to comment the line that prevented from publishing the packaged binary in 2.0.4:

```
//publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false,
```