# Publish zip created by sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to publish to a repository the zip file generated by the *sbt-native-packager* plugin through *universal:packageBin* task.

I configured my project like this:

```
publishTo := Some("Repo" at "http://repo")

publishMavenStyle := true

packagerSettings

packageArchetype.java_application
```

I am struggling trying to create a new sbt task (named publishZip) using publish task and packageBin task to publish the zip file. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Created a documentation request in project itself https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/443

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line to your sbt build (around packagerSettings should be fine)

`deploymentSettings`

Depending on what you want to do you may not need to define the publishZip task you could run

- `sbt universal:publish` which should only publish the zip
- redefine publish so it depends on universal:publish which would publish all the projects artifacts 
  `publish <<= publish.dependsOn(publish in config("universal"))`

Then run sbt publish.

For completeness sake `deploymentSettings` (and `packagerSettings`) come from `com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager` which is useful to know if you use a scala build :)

Comment: I tried `universal:publish` but it only publishes javadoc, jar, sources and pom files. Do I miss a specific configuration ?

Comment: Sorry I missed the lack of deploymentSettings, I have edited my answer with the necessary information.

Comment: If you are using a newer version then you need to add the `UniversalDeployPlugin` to your project instead of using `deploymentSettings`

Answer (score 6):

The `deploymentSettings` worked however I wanted to refine the settings. It seems there were several issues going on. I and finally came up with the following solution:

```
//--use sbt-native-packager default java application 
packageArchetype.java_application

//--a dummy task to hold the result of the universal:packageBin to stop the circular dependency issue
val packageZip = taskKey[File]("package-zip")

//--hard coded result of "universal:packageBin"
packageZip := (baseDirectory in Compile).value / "target" / "universal" / (name.value + "-" + version.value + ".zip")

//--label the zip artifact as a zip instead of the default jar
artifact in (Universal, packageZip) ~= { (art:Artifact) => art.copy(`type` = "zip", extension = "zip") }

//--add the artifact so it is included in the publishing tasks
addArtifact(artifact in (Universal, packageZip), packageZip in Universal)

//--make sure the zip gets made before the publishing commands for the added artifacts
publish := (publish dependsOn (packageBin in Universal)).value

publishM2 := (publishM2 dependsOn (packageBin in Universal)).value

publishLocal := (publishLocal dependsOn (packageBin in Universal)).value
```

The key pieces of this solution came from a [comment from yanns](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/issues/198#issuecomment-38057252) and [dgrandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478262/622016)

Comment: For those seeing this now (2020).  The <<= syntax has been deprecated.  For example the publish step should now be written as: "publish := (publish dependsOn (packageBin in Universal)).value"

Comment: Thank you Michael, I updated and removed the <<= syntax.