# How publish signed artifacts using universal:publish in SBT Native Packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

We are currently deploying to maven central at `oss.sonatype.org`. They require signing published artifacts. For our normal artifacts we are using sbt-gpg to sign and publish.

We use sbt-native-packager to create our binary distributions and we generally us `universal:publish` to push to a repo. I am wondering if there is a way to publish signed artifacts either using sbt-native-packager, stb-gpg or a combination of both.  Following this stack overflow article: [Publish zip created by sbt-native-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558398/publish-zip-created-by-sbt-native-packager) . We can get signed artifacts. But they they show up under `com/example/my-artifact_12.2/1.0.0` instead of `com/example/my-artifac/1.0.0` like they do now.  This may be ok, if it is the best solution.

I also noticed that when publishing them on their own, like we did before. There was no pom file in the `com/example/my-artifac/1.0.0`.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.